# How to get current date and time on highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, utc

I cannot get the current date and time to appear on the x axis of my chart.  As of now it is just a random date and time.  The price is loading in the chart correctly, but the date and time are not.  Using highcharts.  Any help is appreciated thanks.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/chart/ajax_get_chart", // the URL of the controller action method
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            var result = JSON.parse(result);
            var date = new Array();
            var price = new Array();
            var d = new Date();
            series = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                tempArray = Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate());
                tempArray = parseFloat(result[i]['price']);
                tempArray = [result[i]['date']*1000, parseFloat(result[i]['price'])];
                series.push(tempArray);
            }



            console.log(tempArray);
            // var now = new Date();

            Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                }
            });
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'line',
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Bitcoin Price',
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: MtGox.com',
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        pointStart: d.getUTCDate()*1000,
                        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Price'
                    },
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'Bitcoin',
                    data: series
                }]
            });

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you are using in the same time pointStart+pointInterval and [timestamp, value] - so this won't work. Remove that pointStart+pointInterval.

```
 tempArray = [result[i]['date'], parseFloat(result[i]['price'])];
```

Is yout `date` as timestamp in miliseconds (number, not string)?

Comment: I removed the pointStart and pointInterval, but I'm still not getting the current time.  I am also a bit confused as to which series you are talking about.

Comment: When I console.log I get back the current time in unix time, but on the graph it always starts at 20:58:00 and goes up from there.

Comment: Set `useUTC: true` , docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC or make sure you have set. Also, could you show example of data?

Comment: And here is the reason - change from 1371481921 to 1371481921000 (multiply it by 1000) - in Javascript timestamp is millisecond based.

Comment: I am pulling the data from an api, im not sure how to make it so that every timestamp pulled in is multiplied by 1000

Comment: You don't have to, change from: `result[i]['date']` to `result[i]['date'] * 1000 `

Comment: Awesome! It now shows the time in 30 second intervals which is perfect.  The only problem now is that it is showing times from yesterday, Monday June 17

Comment: Setup live example. Problably you don't have UTC dates, for example: 1371481921000 is Mon Jun 17 2013 15:12:01

Comment: Im getting the UTC dates to my page, but instead of the UTC date displaying on the x-axis, I need to convert that to the actual current date and time.

Comment: Awesome! The x-axis now has the correct current time.  The only issue I have now is that when you mouse over the point, the tool tip has yesterdays date.  What causes that?

Comment: Example, example, example.. get generated code (View source) and put into jsFiddle, add missing libraries and show that error.

Comment: When I put my code in jsFiddle it doesnt load. Sorry I'm new to all this stuff.

Comment: Okay, just put there code, and try to fix errors from console. Of course if you have AJAX it won't work.

Comment: Ok I just edited the code above to what I currently have.  I do not have any errors in my console.  The only problem is the tool tip when you hover over a price shows yesterdays date, it has the correct time though.

Comment: For me it works perfectly fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/261/ Update my example with your data from result, please.